# VBA code doesn't work anymore in copied file

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I'm new to VBA and I'm confused.

The code I use works perfectly in a excel file ("Template1") but after copiying "Template1" and rename the copied file "Template2" with the same code, the code doesn't work anymore in "Template2".
Can someone explain me why?
I have no idea why it wouldn't work because the code uses `ThisWorkbook`

Code:

```
Dim FoundCell   As Range, rng As Range
Dim MaxValue    As Long
Dim Search      As String, FirstAddress As String
Dim wsDataImport As Worksheet, wsImportLimesurvey As Worksheet

With ThisWorkbook
    Set wsDataImport = .Worksheets("Dataimport")
    Set wsImportLimesurvey = .Worksheets("ImportLimesurvey")
End With

Search = wsDataImport.Range("M2").Value
If Len(Search) = 0 Then Exit Sub

With wsImportLimesurvey

    Set FoundCell = .Range("L:L").Find(Search, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
        FirstAddress = FoundCell.Address
        Do
           
            With FoundCell.Offset(, -9)
                If .Value > MaxValue Then Set rng = FoundCell: MaxValue = .Value
            End With
           
            Set FoundCell = .Range("L:L").FindNext(FoundCell)
            If FoundCell Is Nothing Then Exit Do
        Loop Until FoundCell.Address = FirstAddress
       
        rng.EntireRow.Copy wsDataImport.Range("A7")
        MsgBox Search & Chr(10) & "Record Copied", 64, "Match Found"
       
    Else
        MsgBox Search & Chr(10) & "Record Not Found", 48, "Not Found"
    End If
End With
```

Thank you in avance.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with *"doesn't work any more"*? How is it called? What does it? Do you get a runtime error? Have you debugged it?

Comment: @FunThomas It simply doesn't do anything, also it doesn't give an error. It's a sub that can be activated with a commandbutton. Normally it finds the correct row and copies it to another row. But it doesn't copy nor paste anything.

Comment: But is it triggered at all? Have you set a breakpoint to check?

Comment: Is that all of it? What module is the code written in? Does it "work" if you type the procedure name (why did you strip the procedure scope declaration?) in the *immediate pane* (Ctrl+G)? What's invoking it and how?

Answer (score 1):

Check if your macros are enabled on this excel file. You can open the VBA editor and try to debug, with the Step Into button, and see how much of your code runs before there is an error. Use the Locals window with Step Into to view the variables if they are correct, depending which line of your code is running.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure template2 is **xlsm** - if all other variables (like sheet names, etc.) are correct and no error message is given, i can't think of another explanation

Answer (score 0):

This proofs that I'm new to VBA, i checked the whole code/macro enabled etc. The problem was : i inserted a new column between C and D, so everything moved one column.
The validation cell wasn't in M2 anymore, but in N2. I thought that the code would change with it.
Sorry for bothering and thank you all for your help.

I'm not gonna delete this post, so if people have the same problem,

Reminder: Check if your cell-references are still the correct cells.